# limits and integrals

Tags: integration, limits, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Show that 
>   $$
>   \lim_{n \to \infty} 
>   \int\limits_{0}^{h} 
>     \frac{\sin (n\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}    
>   \;\mathrm{d}\varepsilon
>   =
>   \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} 
>     \frac{\sin (t)}{t}
>   \;\mathrm{d}t, 
>   \;\;h>0 
> $$

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_0^h \frac{\sin n\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}\, d\varepsilon$ $\displaystyle = \int_0^h \frac{\sin (n\varepsilon)}{n\varepsilon}\, (n\, d\varepsilon)$ $\displaystyle = \int_0^{nh} \frac{\sin t}{t}\, dt.$ ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $t = n\epsilon $. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$